# How write in CV about lecturing experience while being a PhD student

Tags: phd, lecturer

I am currently PhD student, and giving lectures to undergrad students (4 semesters). Is it legit to write about this activity in the CV separately. If yes, then how (i.e. lecturer)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If *lecturer* is an actual title in your location, as it is in many, and you don't actually hold the title, then it would be a mistake to suggest otherwise. If you have full responsibility for a course then you could provide a list of "courses taught". But if you are just a guest lecturer in a course taught by another, you could provide a list of "presentations" with a bit of detail.

Don't say things that others might consider misleading.

You could also seek advice from your current department/school as to how to properly present yourself. Likewise, a professor that you worked for in such courses can provide some guidance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean by saying "actual title in your location"?

Comment: In the US, for example, a person can be hired as a Lecturer. It is a low level academic title. Professor is a high level title. If you hold the title then you can use it, otherwise it might be misleading, depending on where you are and where you are applying. If your actual title is TA, then just use that, even though your actual responsibilities are of a higher order. That was my situation (long ago). I was a TA, but had full responsibility for a Calculus course over a couple of terms. But no title other than TA.

Answer (score 1):

In the United States, if you taught an entire course and did the grading, then you should use a phrase like

"Teaching Experience as Instructor of Record"

followed by a list of the courses.  This would be under teaching experience.  In some other countries this might not be understood.

If you are teaching as a part time job, I would suggest not listing that as employment, but this is a matter of personal preference.

You may need to adjust the way you write this depending on your audience.

Answer (score 0):

When you write your experience section, use subheadings to split it into Research, Teaching, and Administration.  This lecturing goes into the Teaching section.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But which title you suggest to put in "teaching section"?

Comment: It makes very little difference what title you use.  "Lecturer" is as good as any.  Just make sure the description you provide is accurate.

Comment: What are the alternatives to "Lecturer"?

Comment: @sane The title used by the employing institute, for instance

Comment: It depends on the style of the CV you choose.  You can even list the name of the course, with the description "Provided selected lectures", and then you don't need a title.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**I think it is legitimate to add this to your cv , but under the title: Additional academic work.**